# How to change type of a property that gets returned from a method

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a method `useGetAuthorizationWrapper()` which returns `{ data: unknown }` but the expected data that I'll get is an array.

So, when I use `data.length` I'm getting an error. Obviously, I'll get an error because it is of unknown type.

What I need is => I have to change my return type of `data` to an array. How can I modify it while calling `useGetAuthorizationWrapper()` method?

For example like this: `useGetAuthorizationWrapper<{ data: [] }>(); // its not working`

Under the wood `useGetAuthorizationWrapper()` calls `useQuery()` from react-query package

I have searched this issue on the web but didn't get a lead.

Comment: Can you share a bit more code ? And why your example isn't working ?

Comment: It might help you debug if you add the expected type to the hook's function definition. Then your editor will probably catch it. E.g.: export const useGetAuthorizationWrapper = (): {data: any[]}  => { // Hook code here...  }

Comment: My example above is if you wanted the hook to return an Object that contains one property, "data", having a value of Array<any>  -- I'm not sure if that's your goal, but you probably get the idea.

Comment: ```useGetAuthorizationWrapper()``` returns ```UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>``` but how can i modify just the ```data``` property

Comment: You have to provide more code. Probably you are using `axios` or `fetch` without typing...

Answer (score 0):

When receiving an `unknown` type you need to cast it:

```
const wrapper = useGetAuthorizationWrapper();
if (Array.isArray(wrapper.data)) { // just to be sure we have an array
  const data = wrapper.data as any[]; // cast unknown field
  // do your things
} else {
  // handle error
}
```

However, if possible, you can provide types to `useQuery`:

- by specifying the return and error type: https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/typescript#defining-custom-hooks (v2 and v3)
- by typing the function passed to `useQuery` and benefitting from type inference https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/typescript?#type-inference (v4)